# C++ connector для mysql не работает

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, windows

Есть ли какой-нибудь коннектор для MySql?

Я установил сам MySql и там стандартный коннектор не работает! Либо я его неправильно подключил)
[image: f]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего, библиотека не той разрядности.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский так у меня пк х64. Какая разница какая разрядность?..